# How to use regular expression in scanf()?

Tags: c, regex, scanf

I'm trying to read several strings containing whitespace(One string for each line). However, I found only the first scanf() works. After I enter the first string, the result is printed without allowing me enter the second string. Why is that?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str[128];
    char str1[128];
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try this: `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` and so for the rest.

Comment: The first parameter of scanf is not a regex but a formatted string.

Comment: You don't. [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) (and family) doesn't support regular expressions.

Comment: i think you problem is to read lines with spaces in it. you can use `gets` or my previous approach.

Comment: scanf is not used for regular expressions. It can be used for simple formatting.

Comment: Not testing the scanf() return value has always been asking for trouble.

Comment: **DONT USE** `gets`, use `fgets` and strip the `'\n'`

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` fails to save anything into `str` when input begins with `'\n'` leaving it uninitialized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf` doesn't support regular expressions.

But the reason it doesn't work is because between line one and two you are not reading the newline character. With `"%[^\n]"`, `scanf` tries to read one or more characters that are not newlines. The second call doesn't read anything since the next character to be read is `\n`.

So the following will work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char str[128];
    char str1[128];
    scanf("%[^\n]", str);
    getchar();
    scanf("%[^\n]", str1);
    printf("%s\n", str);
    printf("%s\n", str1);
}
```

Comment: It does support character classes, which the OP uses almost correctly, albeit in a case where a more efficient alternative exists.

Comment: Detail: "scanf tries to read zero or more characters that are not newlines." is not so.  It tries to read *one* or more characters that are not newlines.  If the input begins with `'\n'`, nothing is read.

Comment: By `scanf("%[^\n]", str);` not reading input that begins with `'\n'`, `str` is left uninitialized so `printf("%s\n", str);` is undefined behavior.  Same applies to `str1`

Answer (score 0):

You should limit the scan and consume the `'\n'` at the end of each line:

```
scanf("%127[^\n]\n", str);
```

You should check the return value to check if `scanf` indeed scanned a full line.
It could fail for 2 reasons:

- if it is at the end of the file
- more subtle: if the last line in the file is not terminated with a newline.

It would be more efficient to use `fgets` for the job.

Comment: The `'\n'` at the end of `"%127[^\n]\n"` will not only consume the expected `'\n'` but will continue scanning and consume all following white-space until `EOF` or non-whitespace is encountered.  This usually obliges the user to enter another line of input as `stdin` is usually line-buffered.

Comment: scanf is so inadequate ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%[^\n]", str);` never consumes the Enter or `'\n'`.

A simple solution:

```
// scanf("%[^\n]", str);
*str = 0; scanf("%127[^\n]", str);  getchar();
```

`scanf("%[^\n]%*c", str)` fails in various ways:
If user input exceeds buffer size - 1, wich is 128 -1 or 127 for `str`.
If user input is only `'\n'`, nothing is scanned, `str` is left uninitialized and `'\n'` is left in the `stdin` for the next input.

All-in-all, better to use `fgets()`

```
if (fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOForIOerror();
// remove potential trailing `\n`
buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;
```